# Getting error like "There is no registered DBProviderImplementation for the name 'Npgsql'

Tags: c#, database, postgresql

I am working with c#. When I try to get the database schema from PostgreSQL(Npgsql) DB using c#. I have provided `connection string`, `Provider name`, `Database` type to get the schema of the database.

I write the below code for this.

```
public static string DbConnection
{
    get { return _dbConnection; }
    set { _dbConnection = value; }
}
```

and

```
DbConnection = "Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User Id=" + userName + ";Password=" + password;
DbProvider = "Npgsql";
DatabaseType = "Npgsql";
break;
```

I mentioned provider name as `Npgsql` (I have added the namespace also in top of the page as `System.Npgsql;`)

But i get error like

```
There is no registered DBProviderImplementation for the name 'Npgsql'.
```

But for sql and mysql i am successfully getting database schema and actual problem is with postgresql.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a connection as in

```
public class NpgsqlUserManual

    {
      public static void Main(String[] args)
      {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=joe;Password=secret;Database=joedata;");
        conn.Open();
        conn.Close();
      }
    }
```

Here's the link to the wiki: [Npgsql wiki](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual)